# Активация доп. полей после выполнения условия в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Подскажите, как в Unity сделать активными дополнительные поля для ввода после выполнения условия(установки галочки). Заранее спасибо!

Вот пример

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: А что мешает использовать свойство `convex` у компонента `MeshCollider` в коде при выполнении условий?

Comment: Мне надо делать активными совершенно другие поля, к этому примеру и к MeshCollider никакого отношения они не имеют.

Comment: Точно таким же способом. Обращаетесь к конкретному экземпляру компонента и используете его свойства и методы.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, иногда с настройками компонентов работают не только программисты и подобный способ позволяет наиболее явно показать "не специалисту", как ему стоит использовать настройки

Comment: Из вопроса совершенно не ясно, что речь именно про отображение в редакторе....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вам потребуется написать свой [собственный редактор](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) для компонента.
Выглядеть он будет примерно вот так (это пример с заменой рисуемых полей):

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour //ScriptableObject
{
    public bool IsImportantToggle;
    public string FirstField;
    public string SecondString;
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(MyClass))]
public class MyCustomEditor : Editor
{
    MyClass _target;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _target = target as MyClass;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        _target.IsImportantToggle = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Показать первый?", _target.IsImportantToggle);
        if (_target.IsImportantToggle)
        {
            _target.FirstField = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Первое поле: ", _target.FirstField);
        }
        else
        {
            _target.SecondString = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Второе поле: ", _target.SecondString);
        }
    }
}
```

Все классы, которые наследуются от Editor или используют что-то из namespace UnityEditor должны находиться в файлах внутри папки Editor (не обязательно прямо в ней, можно и внутри ещё каких-то папок, главное, чтобы хотя бы одна папка по всему пути до файла называлась Editor - тогда этот скрипт не будет компилироваться в билд). либо, вы можете вписать их код внутрь дефайнов и тогда они тоже нормально скомпилируются:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR

///код использующий редактор

#endif
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Вообще в вопросе спрашивали про `disabled` группы, ну да ладно :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, я думал, что такой эффект достигается с помощью стилей в параметрах метода отрисовки поля, нет?

Comment: @M.Green нет, это disabled группа. Помимо приглушенного цвета они блокируют взаимодействие с контролами.